# [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ContextErrorException]Notice: Array to string conversion

Tags: php, symfony

In my customer repository, I've defined a function `findMapAllByIds()`, like so:

```
/**
 * @apiParam $materialIdList [049c5355-6311-c251-16b7-9c923f8de2a4,0589775e-dcd3-c015-bd81-bba26df33c77,0bf7f653-c01a-d6e2-8cdc-1691c437e4eb]
 */
public function findMapAllByIds($materialIdList, $orderBy = 'createTime', $order = 'desc')
{
    $ids = array();

    $query = $this->createQueryBuilder('Material')
        ->field('_id')->in($materialIdList)
        ->sort($orderBy, $order)
        ->getQuery();

    $resultList = $query->execute();

    $resultMap = array();
    if (!empty($resultList)) {
        foreach ($resultList as $material) {
            $resultMap[(string) $material->getId()] = $material;
        }
    }

    return $resultMap;
}
```

Then, I get this error:

> [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ContextErrorException]
>
> Notice: Array to string conversion

Comment: Hi. Please tell which line the error occurs.

Comment: It's should be `$resultMap[(string) $material->getId()] = $material;`

Comment: Seems like whatever is calling this method is expecting a string instead of the array it returns. You can make your command more verbose by adding --verbose (`-v|vv|vvv, --verbose     Increase the verbosity of messages: 1 for normal output, 2 for more verbose output and 3 for debug`) to your command to get more information about the problem.

Comment: Could it be that your array $materialIdList has more than one level?